# how do I choose desired symbol when linking 2 different versions of the same library?

Tags: gcc, ld, elf

Background: 
I am trying to provide a library wrapped within an interface, to be used in a third party application (MATLAB). 
My problem is that both my library and the third party application rely on Boost libraries.

To make things even worse, not only they rely on two different versions of Boost, but my library is built against a patched version of Boost, and they are statically linked. Third party libraries are instead dynamically linked against Boost.

This is how I link (simplified output of `make -n`)

```
g++ -fPIC ${CPPFLAGS} -shared -lc -ldl ... -Wl,-h,mylib.so -o mylib.so \
${MYSTATICLIBS} \
-L${MATLABLIBSPATH} -lmx -lmex \
-L${MYBOOSTVERSIONPATH} -lboost_thread-gcc49-mt-1_52 ...
```

When I run the library fron within MATLAB then, the wrong boost functions are called from my internal functions (and everything crashes).

My naive intuition was that since i statically linked my Boost, all calls to them from within my library should point to my Boost, while calls from within libmx.so or libmex.so would point to their dynamically loaded dependencies. However this proves my naive intuition was very wrong.

I found different hints here on SO and around the web describing how linking order may break similar situations, however everything describes either all static or all dynamic linking of conflicting symbols.

Suggested solutions are

- using -Bsymbolic -Bsymbolic-functions
- upgrade my library to the same boost version
- changing linking order ( first boost, then -lmx -lmex )
- sell all my earthly possessions, buy a bar on the beach somewhere hot and try making a living out of it
- other??

Can someone explain if and why these solution can work?
( my other problem is, I am not able to test with MATLAB myself, as I have no access to the machines on which it is installed. this is why I'm also asking "if" the proposed solutions would work)

Comment: "and they are statically linked" - are you 100% sure that you link against static version of Boost? Does output of `readelf --dyn-syms -W youlib.so` show Boost symbols as defined (rather than "UND")?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, welcome to the wonderful world of Linux symbol interposition ;)

I think what happens is your library exports all symbols from Boost library it has been linked with (can be verified with `readelf --dyn-syms -W`). At runtime, dynamic linker will note that and instead rebind symbols to a *different* version of Boost (because it happens to be loaded earlier and so overrides symbols used by your library).

What you want to do is to tell gcc that you do not want to export Boost symbols or you do not want them to be interposable at runtime. There are several solutions for this, the best being to compile and link with `-fvisibility=hidden` (note that Boost will also need to be linked with this flag). This will prevent any functions from being exported from your library unless you explicitly mark them with `__attribute__((visibility("hidden")))` (you'll need to annotate library interface functions of course).

Another option is `-Bsymbolic` - this would not prevent spurious Boost exports from your library but would at least prevent dynamic linker from overriding them with random versions of Boost functions which happen to be loaded by other libraries.

Now to remaining questions.

> upgrade my library to the same boost version

You could do that but this may break if 3-rd party upgrades their Boost at some point.

> changing linking order ( first boost, then -lmx -lmex )

Does not make much sense... Have you tried?